# C# SQL Query Want to Check Whether There is Already an exist data between Start Time and End Time

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to add new Appointment but maybe I have some logic issue to retrieve the data between start time and end time. Is there any issue on my query?

I have a database data of
AssignStartTime 03-Aug-22 8:00:00 AM and
AssignEndTime 03-Aug-22 12:00:00 PM.

When I was trying to insert new appointment with the same 03-Aug-22 8:00:00 AM until 03-Aug-22 12:00:00 PM it work fine with showing there is already an appointment exist.

**But**, when I insert new appointment with either 03-Aug-22 9:00:00 AM until 03-Aug-22 12:00:00 PM or 03-Aug-22 8:00:00 AM until 03-Aug-22 11:00:00 AM it will be insert success (it suppose also show there is already an exist appointment?).

Appreciate for help... Thanks. Below is the code

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblAssignDoctor 
WHERE AssignStartTime >= '03-Aug-22 8:00:00 AM' AND AssignEndTime <= '03-Aug-22 12:00:00 PM'
```

[image: image with data found]

this work fine but when I change to

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblAssignDoctor 
WHERE AssignStartTime >= '03-Aug-22 8:00:00 AM' AND AssignEndTime <= '03-Aug-22 11:00:00 AM'
```

there will be no data be shown even i have a
data between 8am to 12pm.

[image: Image of no data found]

Appreciate for the help... Thanks.

Comment: Right now this doesn't look like a C# question. Please [edit] your post with a [mre].

Comment: Use `AssignEndTime >= '03-Aug-22 8:00:00 AM' AND AssignStartTime <= '03-Aug-22 11:00:00 AM'`. You need to find overlap, if exists, so you compare ending point of one range with starting point of another range, and starting point of first range with ending point of second range. I.E. two ranges overlap if first range starts before second ends and first range ends after second range starts.

Comment: the mysql dateform is 2022-08-02 12:12:12  if save and query the dates  in this format

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović tried and it work~ thanks